# Is this expression on limit valid and/or meaningful?

Tags: limits

Just out of curiosity, so is the result of following expression defined and meaningful (just makes sense)?

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim_{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) \rightarrow (1^{-},1^{-},...,1^{-})}{a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_n }}$

Does it equal to 0?

*I just had that thought looking through probability books.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $n$, certainly $$\lim_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\to (1,\ldots,1)}a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n=1 $$
Therefore, taking the limit of this as $n\to \infty$ is still $1$.

Comment: Ugh, I got to admit that anyway yes, certainly but it's just counter-intuitive.